# ROI in OpenCV from Android

Tags: java, android, opencv

I want to use ROI in OpenCV for Android.

This is code true?

```
Mat image = new Mat();
Mat imageRIO = new Mat();
Rect roi = new Rect(300, 50, 50, 10);

public Mat onCameraFrame(CvCameraViewFrame inputFrame) {
    image = inputFrame.gray();

    image.submat(roi);  //set roi
    image.copyTo(imageRIO);
    return imageRIO;
 }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Error setting ROI OpenCV Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14695428/error-setting-roi-opencv-android)

Answer (score 5):

I am not sure exactly what you are trying to do, but `submat()` returns a Mat that you need and you are not assigning it to anything. `image.copyTo()` copies `image` not the submat you extracted in the previous line.

You could simply do this:

```
Rect roi = new Rect(300, 50, 50, 10);

public Mat onCameraFrame(CvCameraViewFrame inputFrame) {
    return new Mat(inputFrame.gray(), roi);
}
```